# Is queryMode: 'local' optional when working with a ComboBox and a local store ?

Tags: javascript, extjs

What is the use of setting `queryMode:` to `local` when working with a local store ? In the following Fiddle, it does not make any differences if I set the queryMode to `remote`

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/n67

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it makes a difference in your case, because you are not searching the values. If you update your combobox config to make it searchable by setting

```
editable: true,
queryMode: 'remote'
```

you will see that the data is not filtered correctly. Yet setting

```
editable: true,
queryMode: 'local'
```

will yield the correct filters that search your data.

There may also be other implications such as paging when the setting is not configured correctly.